# "A manual written to help students to understand the module"

Tags: grammar

Or should it be without the second "to" like this: "A manual written to help students understand the module"? I'm guessing that either is generally acceptable but is there a traditional grammar rule about this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Cambridge Dictionary [suggests](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/help-somebody-to-do) that you can use the infinitive with or without *to*:

> Jack is helping me to tidy my CDs. or Jack is helping me tidy my CDs.

When "understand" lacks a *to* but functions as an infinitive, it is called a [bare infinitive](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv226.shtml). These bare infinitives are sometimes interchangeable with to-infinitives, depending on the verb. "To help" is [one such verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb).

So the only difference is which one you like better for other reasons, like personal preference.

Comment: Did you check for duplicates?